# BigQuery Atomicity

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to do a full load of a table in big query daily, as part of ETL. The target table has dummy partition column of type integer and is clustered. I want to have the statement to be atomic i.e either it will completely overwrite the new data or rollback to old data in case of failure for any reason in between and it will serve user queries with old data until it completely overwritten.

One way of doing this is delete and insert but big query does not support multi statement transactions.

I am thinking to use the below statement. Please let me know if this is atomic.

```
create or replace table_1 partition by dummy_int cluster dummy_column
as select col1,col2,col3 from stage_table1
```

Comment: Since you want to do an insert and delete, have you thought of using the **MERGE** statement? It combines **INSERT**, **UPDATE** and **DELETE**  and they are atomic operations. You can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement).

Comment: Two things here                                                                                                        1. I want to do delete and insert for the same match clause and not sure if this is supported.                                                                                                                       2. Merge will do a row by row operation which I think will be slow.                                               If there had been insert overwrite in Standard SQL, it would have solved my problem. Instead of that I am trying `create or replace`.

Comment: if you want to delete and then insert, I belive you could use the UPDATE method instead when the condition is matched. Here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) for the documentation, let me know if that suits your case so I can provide a query syntax for you.